# Is using regex to check columns in database wrapper overkill?

Tags: php, sql, regex

Here's an example wrapper for an SQL query

```
public function where ($col, $val)
{
    if (!preg_match('~^[a-z0-9_]+$~i', $col))
        throw new Exception('Invalid parameter $col');

    $this->where.= "WEHERE $col = :$col";
}
```

Is this quite overkill since regex is probably using resources.
Note I am actually using this to wrap PDO (notice the colon in :$col).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$col` can be specified through user input then this is not overkill but rather *your only defense* against SQL injection.

If `$col` is known safe (for example your code produces its value with a `switch` statement) then it's probably not worth it to include the runtime check. But you should take into account the possibility of the "known safe" status changing as the program is maintained in the future.

Comment: SQL injection prevention is a rather poor example, as you should be using mysqli or a similar prepared statement library anyway.

It is mainly useful to do a last sanity check on string data to see if e.g. a telephone number passed by the user is in the expected format before you hit the database.

Comment: @JBert: I am assuming you have either not read the question carefully (PDO is used), or glossed over the difference between binding *values* to a prepared statement and binding *schema object names* (which is not possible at all AFAIK).

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my comment (must have been my brain shutting down). I'd hate to see the application where the user is expected to enter column names though...

Comment: I'm just writing a class to help speed up SQL query writing so no end user input will go through it but rather it's for the programmers use. I just thought of adding an extra layer of security by making sure no weird characters are entered.